# post request with jquery not going through

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++, ajax, http

So I have the following jquert code

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/game',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
           if (data.status != "ok") {
               console.log(data);
               alert(data);
           }
        },
        data: {game_id : 1, game_stage : 1}
});
```

or even if i change it to this

```
$.post("/game", {game_id:1, game_stage:1}, function(data) {
   if (data.status != "ok") {
       console.log(data);
       alert(data);
   }
}, 'json');
```

And I have a C++ server to debug this that just outputs the raw HTTP request sent over and I always get this for some reason

```
POST /game HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://localhost:5000
Content-Length: 22
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/601.4.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.3 Safari/601.4.4
Referer: http://localhost:5000/
DNT: 1
```

Why does the JSON object not get passed into the request?  A similar GET request works just fine.

This is my first time using JavaScript so forgive my stupid mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
url: '/game',
```

To

```
url: 'game',
```

I'm assuming 'game' is in the current directory with no extension.

Comment: Nope makes no difference.  A get request with the same syntax works just fine

Comment: It's not a GET request it's a POST request. I had an error when I tested it but maybe I'm wrong. You could try entering the `console.log(data);` just before your `if (data.status != "ok") {` to properly log the error message.

Comment: I know.. I am trying to do the same and it is not working at all.  I am returning a JSON HTTP response from a flask server

Comment: You might want to check out $.parseJSON() in jquery: [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this :

```
$.ajax({
url: '/game',
type:"POST",
data: {game_id : 1, game_stage : 1} ,
contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType:"json",
success: function(data){
  if (data.status != "ok") {
   console.log(data);
   alert(data);
}
}
});
```

Comment: No JSON going through still for some reason... Have you gotten this to work somehow?

Comment: yes .  I think then something is wrong with the handler file . Can you show me the file where the data is passed?

Comment: Nope there is no data coming in at all.  I checked using a C++ server which reads in the bytes.  There is no data coming in.  Is there an example online that I could download and run to see what is happening?